# Text replace in a file, on 5h line, from position 18 to position 145

Tags: shell, sed

I have this text file:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "auth": true,
    "username": "rtorrent",
    "password": "d5275b68305438499f9660b38980d6cef7ea97001efe873328de1d76838bc5bd15c99df8b432ba6fdcacbff82e3f3c4829d34589cf43236468d0d0b0a3500c1e"
}
```

Now, I want to be able to replace the **d5275b68305438499f9660b38980d6cef7ea97001efe873328de1d76838bc5bd15c99df8b432ba6fdcacbff82e3f3c4829d34589cf43236468d0d0b0a3500c1e** using sed for example. (The string has always the exact same length, but the values can be different)

I've tried this using **sed**:

```
sed -i 5s/./new-string/18 file.json
```

That basically replaces text, on the 5th line, starting with position 18. I want to be able to replace the text, exactly starting with position 18 and up to position 154, strictly what's inside the `""`. The command above will cut the `",` at the end of the file and if it's run multiple times, the string becomes every time longer and longer.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example awk for it:

```
$ awk -v var="new_string" 'NR==5{print substr($0,1,17) var substr($0,146);next}1' file
{
    "name": "",
    "auth": true,
    "username": "rtorrent",
    "password": "new_string"
}
```

but there are better tools for changing a value in a JSON, `jq` for example:

```
$ jq '.password="new_string"' file
{
  "name": "",
  "auth": true,
  "username": "rtorrent",
  "password": "new_string"
}
```

**Edit**: When passing a shell variable `$var` to awk and `jq`:

```
$ var="new_string"
$ awk -v var="$var" 'NR==5{print substr($0,1,17) var substr($0,146);next}1' file
```

and

```
$ jq --arg var "$var" '.password=$var'
```

**Edit2**: There is always `sed`:

```
$ sed -i "5s/\"[^\"]*\"/\"$var\"/2" file
```

Comment: Thanks, both works... One more thing tho, I should have specified from the start... if the new string is the value of a variable? how that can be achieved? since in both examples, if I replace `new_string` with `$variable` for example it won't put the var value...

Comment: Updated the answer to handle variables.

Comment: Thanks again, it works just fine but it doesn't actually do the replace, but only the printing (for both examples). If I ran any of the commands, the output on screen is correct, if I check then the file, it's still with the original values

Comment: Yeah, you need to redirect the output to a new file and replace the old file with that. GNU awk (after version 4.0 IIRC) has inplace edit with `-i inplace`. See edit2.